# How to color html text?

Tags: html, css, swift

I'm making pdf by iOS app and I just want to change title text color in Swift.

This is the black title:

```
let pageTitle = "<b>THIS IS TITLE</b>"
```

*I tried this and got error:*

```
let pageTitle = "<p color="red"><b>THIS IS TITLE</b></p>"
```

*Also I tried this one and also got error:*

```
let pageTitle = "<p style="color:red;"><b>THIS IS TITLE</b></p>"
```

I guess problem is just because of the symbol **"**. I replaced it by symbol **'** but still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved by adding CSS code with single quote!
This gives red:

```
let pageTitle = "<p style='color:red;'><b>THIS IS TITLE</b></p>"
```

Comment: did this work? looks like it would throw a quote mismatch error

Comment: @Pete oh you are right! I replaced it by single quote.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
<p style="color:red"><b></b></p>
```

and if you have more than one css styles to apply

you can do this:

```
<label style="style1:value2;style2:value2"></label>
```

i have a test on online css style website it works.so,you synax maybe wrong

Comment: double quote is not a good idea. It brokes the line. That's why I replaced it instead of single quote

Answer (score 0):

look  at your code:

```
  let pageTitle = "<p style="color:red;"><b>THIS IS TITLE</b></p>"
```

your nested double quotation "" in "" ,maybe you can try
      let pageTitle ="**THIS IS TITLE**

"
change 
        sytle="color:red;"  to style='color:red;'